# Live upgrade attempt and I get a table error 'coupon_aggregated_updated' doesn't exist

Tags: magento-enterprise, mysql, upgrade

I was able to upgrade on my local no problem, but now I am trying on the server and I get this error? I looked at the ugpraded db and I don't have that table.

```
Error in file: "app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/sql/salesrule_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.1-1.6.0.2.php" - SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'coupon_aggregated_updated' doesn't exist
```

Magento EE 1.12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the table has not been created or has been removed :(

Not sure why this would happen but the table should have been created in the setup script `app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/sql/salesrule_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.0-1.6.0.1.php`. From your error message it appears that it is trying to run 1.6.0.1 to 1.6.0.2 so I am not sure why the other one has not been run.

I would suggest you could reset the sales rule value in the core_resource table so that it reruns both scripts.